# How to get child variable from parent Angular 2

Tags: angular, variables, typescript

I load a component with method viewContainerRef.createComponent() and store it in a variable.

That component has child components and I need to obtain the variable from one kind of childs.

The code will be something like that:

Parent:

```
<div #childLoader></div>

this.loadedChild1 = this.childLoader.createComponent(child1);
```

Child1:

`<child2></child2>`
`<another></another>`
`<child2></child2>`

Child2:

```
@Component({  
  selector: 'child2',
  templateUrl: 'child2.html'
})
export class Child2Component {

@Input() title: string;
public getTitle(){
 return this.title;
}
}
```

What I'm trying after loading parent component is to acces title, other public var or in fact  getTitle() method ignoring the other childs of Child1.

I'm trying to get child2 method/var from this.loadedChild1.

Is that possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I see that you used @Input for inputting data into the child. It's the other way around for output with @Output

In your child1 component

```
@Output()
notify: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

sendTitle(): void {
  this.notify.emit(this.title);
}
```

In your parent html

```
<child1 (notify)="getChildTitle($event)"></child1>
```

In your parent component

```
getChildTitle(title: string): void{
  console.log("Received child's title: " + title);
}
```

Great article on this: https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/building-nested-components-in-angular-2/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't want to modify child1, and it 0-n child2. I load child1 into parent with this <div #childLoader></div> and child1 could be childX

Answer (score 1):

```
import {ViewChild, QueryList} from "@angular/core";

@Component({  
  selector: 'child1',
  templateUrl: 'child1.html'
})
export class Child1Component {
 @ViewChildren(Child2Component) childs2:QueryList<Child2Component>;
 ngAfterViewInit() {
   //do something
    this.childs2.forEach((child2)=>{

      child2.getTtile();
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: it didn't works for me. Parent have Child2Component and i'm trying to access to child1 children (wich contains child2) from code from this.loadedComponent(this is child1 loaded).

Comment: child1 is only an example. I have multiple components that contains child2 inside and I abstract it to child1 for explanation. child1  could contain different methods, inputs and outputs, but some have child2 (1 or many) included.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my code, the parent in my code is your child1, see the update

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I'm trying to avoid modify child1 component because I have hundreds without the ViewChild on it that will include more than one child2 and need to return to Parent all the titles (maybe with an array or json)

Comment: This doesn't work to get it from the parent, but to read it from the child it works perfectly. Thanks